# How to display image from URI of the image in HTML code in react native for ANDROID?

Tags: html, react-native

I am using 'react-native-image-picker' for choosing an image from Gallery/Camera. it is giving the response, and I am using URI of the response to display an image in the HTML and generating PDF from the HTML. Now, I am able to display the image in PDF from the stored URI in iOS but not in Android. Please tell me what am I doing wrong?. My code is below:

```
getDataForHtmlAndGeneratePDF = async () => {
    let CandidatePhotoUrl = await
        AsyncStorage.getItem('CandidatePhotoUrl'); // getting image uri from async storage which i stored in another class. 

    const htmlString = `
           <!DOCTYPE html>
           <html>
           <head>
           <style>
           table.Rating, table.Rating th, table.Rating td {
             border: 1px solid black;
             border-collapse: collapse;
           }

           table.Rating th {
           border-Top: 2px solid black;
           border-Left: 2px solid black;
           border-Right: 2px solid black;
           background-color: LightGray;
           padding: 15px;
           }
           table.Rating td {
           border-Left: 2px solid black;
           border-Right: 2px solid black;
           padding: 10px;
           }

           </style>
           </head>
           <body style="justifyContent: 'center'">
           <div style=" height: 100px;
               width: 100%; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
               <Text align="center" style = "padding-Top: 5px; font-size: 32px; margin-left: 10px;font-weight: bold;"> 
               Technical Interview Assessment Sheet</Text>
           </div>

           <br>
           <table style="width:100%">
             <tr height="50">
               <td style="width:117px">Candidate Name:</td>
               <td style="width:55%">${candidateName}</td>
               <td rowspan="2"><img src= ${this.ShowImageForCandidate(CandidatePhotoUrl)}  align="top" style="width:80px;height:80px;" /></td>
             </tr>
             </table>
           </table>
           </body>
           </html>
           `;

    let options = {
        //Content to print
        html: htmlString,
        //File Name
        fileName: 'feedback',
        //File directory
        directory: 'docs',
    };

    let file = await RNHTMLtoPDF.convert(options);

}

ShowImageForCandidate = (photoUrl) => {
    if (photoUrl != null) {
        return photoUrl
    } else {
        return 'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/17/17004.svg'
    }
}
```

response structure is like this: 
[image]
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

React Native doesn't support HTML tags, instead you can use [Image component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image) of react-native itself.

```
<View>
    <Image
      style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
      source={{uri: this.ShowImageForCandidate(CandidatePhotoUrl)}}
    />
</View>
```

If you are trying to using web view then let me know I can correct my answer.

Comment: Yes, I know that but I am generating a PDF from HTML itself with the help of a 3rd part i.e 'react-native-html-to-pdf'. So I just updated my question, please have a look.

Comment: Ok can you please tell what was passed to src in html?

Comment: For Android, URI is a string i.e 'content://com.reactnativepoc.provider/root/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/images/image-name.jpg'.

Comment: @GulshanKumar In AsyncStorage you are saving `response.uri` right?

Comment: Yes, I am storing it in AsyncStorage.